# Is there a way to have a function as an argument, but somehow modify the function call before the return value is given?

Tags: python

For reference, I am a beginner.

I am trying to make a function that 'tests' other functions, nothing complex or anything. It's easier to show than explain:

```
def test(function, actual, expected):
    print("Testing ", function)
    print("Expected result:", expected,  "Actual result:", actual)
```

As it stands, the name of the function and the argument are entered separately as a string:

```
test("function(5)", function(5), expected)
```

I am looking for a way to get the actual function call (the second argument/parameter) as a string ("function(5)", in this case), because right now it is treated as the return value as soon as the 'test' function is called.

Comment: i think you're looking for a decorator

Comment: @hjpotter92 That solution would make it much cleaner, but it would also tightly couple the test with the source code.

Comment: In Python, all arguments are *fully evaluated* before being passed. You are calling `function(5)` *first* and then the result of that is being passed to `test`. Just *pass the function* and do the call inside `test`

Comment: @TedKleinBergman yes, I agree, it wouldn't be much cleaner either. A function is plenty clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the parameters to the function as arguments. This is how python's unit test framework does it. Your function would then look something like this:

```
def test(function_name, expected, function, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Testing ", function_name)
    print("Expected result:", expected, "Actual result:", function(*args, **kwargs))

test("function(5)", expected, function, 5)
```

Every argument or keyword argument pass the function will be unpacked into the function.

The reason why I moved the `expected` argument before the function is so there wouldn't be any ambiguity in of what's suppose to be an argument to the `test` function and what's suppose to be passed into `function`.

Another solution which lets you omit the name:

```
def test(expected, function, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs_repr = [f'{a}={b}' for a, b in kwargs.items()]
    arguments   = ', '.join(str(arg) for arg in (*args, *kwargs_repr)) 
    print(f"Testing if {function.__name__}({arguments}) equals {expected}")
    print("Expected result:", expected, "Actual result:", function(*args, **kwargs))

test(expected, function, 5)
```

To be even more complete, you should also catch any errors that might be thrown from the function.

```
def test(expected, function, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs_repr = [f'{a}={b}' for a, b in kwargs.items()]
    arguments   = ', '.join(str(arg) for arg in (*args, *kwargs_repr)) 
    print(f"Testing if {function.__name__}({arguments}) equals {expected}")
    try:
        print("Expected result:", expected, "Actual result:", function(*args, **kwargs))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Function raised exception: {e}")

test(None, print, 5, 3, end=' ', abc='hello')
```

> Testing print(1, 2, sep=123, end=hello, abc=123)
>
> Function raised exception: 'abc' is an invalid keyword argument for print()